# How to select option in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I need to add javascript or jquery code in order to select option from combobox. There are 25 comboboxes and there value read from database. Please find below code fragment

option which is selected by user needs to be selected. It has to be read from database.

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">A. Nails are Clean *</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="obs_chart_nails_clean" >
            <option value="Always">Always</option>
            <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>    
            <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>               
        </select>
      </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it from javascript?

Comment: I am using coodeigniter! Is better way to do it.

Comment: Is simply doing `<option value="Rarely" selected>` possible?

Comment: but how to do it in codeigniter where I have variable $row->obs_chart_nails_clean and in it Rarely value.

Comment: I don't know CI, so... an if-block within each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `id` attribute to `select`

```
<select name="obs_chart_nails_clean" id="obs_chart_nails_clean">
```

and add **jquery** to your page, then

```
$(document).read(function(){
    $("#obs_chart_nails_clean").val("Rarely");
});
```

will select third option.

What do you have server-side? You should be able to produce html with correct option already selected.

Comment: I am using codeigniter and in views How can i select those values?

Comment: I haven't done any work in CodeIgniter, but certainly there is a way produce html dynamically in a view. You can looking in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, the obvious no-javascript solution must be noted:

```
<select name="obs_chart_nails_clean" >
    <option value="Always">Always</option>
    <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>    
    <option value="Rarely" selected>Rarely</option>               
</select>
```

Simply add the `selected` attribute to one of the `option`s.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#obs_chart_nails_clean').val("Sometimes");
});
```

Comment: Please provide the detail answer. If you look at the questions, there is no ID in the select tag but you have use the ("#") ID selector. Either provide detail answer or use the tag name as selector